# Run a number of mongodb queries using async node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

I have a service that gets the following parts in req.body :

```
  dataType: null,
  fechaI: null,
  fechaF: null,
  checkedList: []
```

i have to run the number of queries equal to the length of checked list and return a single response to the client.
I have another file called queries.js that exports all queries i use so lets say i want to get all documents and get their sum  I would simply do this

```
const queries = require('./queries.js')
// example in the controller 
exports.example = function(req,resp){
   query.ej(req,resp)
}
```

what i wanna achieve is : 
1. Iterate over all items in checked list and executing the query 
2. Return a single array with the results of all the queries

I have tried using async.paralel but the properties from req dont get passed to the query function and i dont think the function will return all the results

```
async.parallel([
        function(cb){

            for( var i=0;i<req.body.checkedList.length;i++){
                  //res is used to store the temporary variables to be passed on to the query
                var res ={ }
                res.context= { 
                    sujeto :"TOS060602S77",
                    type : req.body.dataType,
                    fechaInicio : req.body.fechaI,
                    fechaFin : req.body.fechaF,
                    moneda : req.body.checkedList[i].moneda
                }

                query[req.body.checkedList[i].action](req,res,resp,cb)


            }
        }


       ], function(err,results){
           console.log(results)

       })
```

Heres an example query from query.js file :

```
exports.action= function(req,resp,res, callback){
    MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,client){
        if (err) console.log(err)
        let dbo = client.db("SomeDB")
        var collection ="Somecollection"
        console.log(res.context)
        dbo.collection(collection).aggregate([
                   //do something
        ]).toArray(function(err,data){

            if (err) callback(err)
            if (!data) console.log(" no data")
            if (data) {

               var results= {datos : data}
                callback(data)
                console.log(results)
            }

        })


    })

}
```

Essentially the error i get is that the object passed to the query is undefined when executed and probably the structure of the async.parallel method , for i dont think it returns all results in a single response.

Comment: where is query Object?

Comment: query object is an import from another js file in which i have a mongodb query like in the last code example

Comment: just print qyery object